# How to configure the TypeScript compiler to target one environment with specific additional syntax from a newer one?

Tags: typescript, tsc

My actual target environment is the [iOS Scriptable app](https://scriptable.app/), which states:

> Scriptable uses Apples [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore), which supports [ECMAScript 6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)

so my [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) includes

```
"target": "ES2015"
```

However, Scriptable also supports some modified syntax beyond ES2015, like `async/await`, top-level `await`, top-level `return`, etc.

How do I configure TypeScript to support these modifications and not transform the related syntax? (e.g. I don't want helpers like `__awaiter`, and I don't want TS to generate errors related to top-level `await`, `return`, etc.)

I'm not sure what to do in this case. Is there a way to configure a custom target to not transform certain syntax and suppress certain "errors"?

I also found this issue, which is related to this question: [Suggestion: target specific runtimes instead of JS versions #19183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19183)

Comment: As far as I'm aware TSC doesn't support detailed configuration there, just the targets listed in https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, I'm thinking I'm going to have to use Babel, but was hoping to avoid it.